# JavaScript get anchor href on click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How can I get the href of an anchor when I click on it using JavaScript?
I did the following:

```
function myFunc() {
}
window.onclick = myFunc;
```

But how to extend the function to respond only to clicks on anchors and get the href?

Comment: The href of an anchor? Isn't an anchor like a pin on the page with it's own name? It has no href. If you want to get the href of any link then I recommend using jquery

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
function linkClick(e) {
  alert(e.target.href);
}
links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
  links[i].addEventListener('click', linkClick, false);
```

Comment: Note that if you have another element inside your anchor (e.g. <a href="mysite.com"><div class="button"><p>this is a link</p></div></a>) , e.target will likely be (in the above example) the <div> or the <p> and won't have the href attribute defined on it. In these cases, you need to traverse the DOM until you hit the <a> element

Answer (score 2):

Your `document.onclick` registers the handler on the whole document. But you should add it to every link. You can do this with JavaScript and using a framework like Prototype or jQuery makes it a lot easier:

```
$$('a').invoke('observe', 'click', function(a){
    myFunc(a);
});
```

But you can also use pure JS combining the `getElementsByTagName` function with a loop (see Delan's new answer).

Comment: It's really disappointing when you get down votes without any comment.

Comment: Your answer is good, but I need the solution without jQuery because jQuery is a bit overload for my issue. Thanks! :)

Comment: It was a Prototype and not jQuery solution and I also pointed out how to do it without a framework. And you didn't tell use that you don't want use a framework or don't even have a framework in use.

Answer (score 1):

it won't work like this, you need to setup an onclick handler for every anchor. The easiest way to do this, is to use a javascript framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) or something similar.

extend your function to recieve the calling object:

```
var myFunc = function(target) {
  var href = target.href;
  // ... your function code that can now see the href of the calling anchor
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  myFunc(this);
});
```

Protype: see [Kau-Boy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299375/kau-boy)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022069/javascript-get-anchor-href-on-click/3022092#3022092)

Comment: Your Prototype isn't correct. I posted exactly the same before. Have a look on my answers to see how to do that in Prototype.

Answer (score -1):

```
function myFunc(link) {
  alert(link.href);
  return false; // return false if you don't want to actually navigate to that link
}


<a href onclick="return myFunc(link)">something</a>
```