# Prevent JavaScript in parent.window.opener.location

Tags: javascript, window.opener

I'm trying to prevent page closing when clicking on a external link used this JavaScript code.
code is running in that other page.

```
if(parent.window.opener) parent.window.opener.location='//www.domain.com';
```

I have a lot of links, difficult removed or use window.onbeforeunload annoying.

Is there any code do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022069/javascript-get-anchor-href-on-click)

Comment: I do not understand your first sentence. So a person clicks on a link to another domain and that JavaScript code above is running in that other page? How do the links play role in that code above?

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9744104/1543447)

```
    var domain = function(url) {
        return url.replace('http://','').replace('https://','').split('/')[0];
    };

    return domain(location.href) !== domain(url);
}
```

Use it here to prevent the default behavior of a link:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a').addEventListener("click", function(e){
if(domain(e.target.href)){
e.preventDefault();
}
}, false);
```